# How to raise requests Timeout Exception?

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        print e
        raise Timeout("some message %s" % (str(e)))
```

Im trying to raise a requests Timeout exception if a server takes too long to respond. Is this the correct way to raise the exception? Im not able to test this yet so just learning more about raising this exception.

Comment: may be you should be able to test it by turning off your wifi (disconnecting your internet in general)

Comment: Yes, if server takes too long to respond. But then the entire request in itself can take *days* without an exception being thrown. Also could just catch `except Timeout as e:` - also, why would you raise the new exception and just not the original

Comment: you're right, i can just raise the original exception.